Is there any Complex Analysis book that is very "analysis"?
I have learned Complex Analysis for once, and I'm trying to review it. Then I found out that most Complex Analysis books are not very "analysis". That is, for typical analysis books(elementary Mathematical Analysis, Real Analysis, or Fourier Analysis), one can find a lot of inequalities, calculations, tricks, and stuff like these. However,at least for the Complex Analysis books I read, there are not too many of these things. Instead, a lot of Complex Analysis books are more focused on "Topology" or "Geometry" like the one by Ahlfors.
Furthermore, when I use the Residue Theorem to calculate an integral, sometimes I encounter a problem that there are singular points. However, so far I also haven't found a book that teaches you how to deal with the difficulty of discussing the principal branch when singular points appear. (Or even explain it clearly)
Thus, I'm wondering if are there books for Complex Analysis that are pretty "analysis" or if some books can clearly explain the principal branch and residue integral without systematically introducing Riemann Surface. Thank you very much!

Look This Book : The Cauchy method of residues: Theory and applications, by Dragoslav Mitronivić and Jovan Kečkić.

Look this book The Cauchy method of residues: Theory and applications, by Dragoslav Mitronivić and Jovan Kečkić.
